# Need clarity on _SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH

Tags: winapi, driver

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid_and_attributes_hash

```
typedef struct _SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH {
   DWORD               SidCount;
   PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES SidAttr;
   SID_HASH_ENTRY      Hash[SID_HASH_SIZE];
} SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH, *PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES_HASH;
```

This has an array of `SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` with `SidCount` number of SIDs. Why is there more than one SID present in the structure when a Windows user can have only one SID? Which one from the array is the correct SID of the user?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there more than one SID present in the structure when a Windows user can have only one SID?

Because SIDs aren't just used to represent users, they are also used to represent groups, capabilities, etc. A token only ever contains one user SID but it can contain multiple group SIDs, multiple capability SIDs, etc.

For the `SidHash` field of `TOKEN_ACCESS_INFORMATION` – this appears to store both user AND group SIDs. The `SidCount` is greater than 1, because it is normal for the user to belong to several groups.

Similarly, the `CapabilitiesHash` field of `TOKEN_ACCESS_INFORMATION` stores capability SIDs. To give an example, if your process has both `SECURITY_CAPABILITY_PICTURES_LIBRARY` and `SECURITY_CAPABILITY_VIDEOS_LIBRARY` then `SidCount` of that instance of this structure would be 2. Capability SIDs are used to represent what actions sandboxed apps (Windows Store Apps) are allowed to perform. So, in this example, the app has permission to access both the user's "Pictures" directory and their "Videos" directory.

> Which one from the array is the correct SID of the user?

For the `SidHash` field of `TOKEN_ACCESS_INFORMATION`: you may find that the first SID is the user SID, and the remaining SIDs are group SIDs. However, that is not guaranteed. If you need the user SID specifically, you are safer just directly asking for it using `TokenGetInformation` with a `TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS` of `TokenUser`

Comment: The order of the entries is not usually significant, and grabbing the first one on the assumption that it is the user sid is most likely just being lucky. If you want the SID for the user, ask for TokenUser, which returns a single `SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for the feedback, I edited the answer in response

Answer (score 0):

The [SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid_and_attributes) represents a security identifier (SID) and its attributes.

A security identifier (SID) is used to uniquely identify a security principal or security group. A security identifier is a data structure in binary format that contains a variable number of values. The first values in the structure contain information about the SID structure.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Security identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers)

Comment: does not answer my question.

Comment: >>Why is there more than one SID present in the structure when a Windows user can have only one SID? 

I suggest you could refert to the Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers#security-identifiers-and-globally-unique-identifiers

Contains previous SIDs used for the object if the object was moved from another domain. Whenever an object is moved from one domain to another, a new SID is created and that new SID becomes the objectSID. The previous SID is added to the sIDHistory property.